# Kesuvos or Kesubos?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

The main tag on the second tractate of Seder Nashim is [maseches-kesuvos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-kesuvos), with other variant spellings synonymized to it.

However, the correct transliteration should be kesubos (or ketubot), [since the ב has a dagesh.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30804/759)

Answer (score 3):

I guess so. Done. [maseches-kesubos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-kesubos)